# Spring bean interface declaring

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have a work class :

```
public class WorkClass implements ApplicationContextAware {
   ... // has access to ApplicationContext
}
```

Have some useful interface :

```
public interface UsefulInterface {
    void doUseful();
}
```

Have some impl class that can do much more:

```
public class CanDoAlmostEverything implements UsefulInterface {
    ...
}
```

I want to provide UsefulInterface implementation (via CanDoAlmostEverything) to WorkClass using Spring, but NOT to access any other CanDoAlmostEverything methods exept "doUseful"

In other words I want to declare my bean[s] like :

```
<bean id="workerA" interface="UsefulInterface" class="CanDoAlmostEverything"/>
<bean id="workerB" interface="UsefulInterface" class="AnotherUsefulImpl"/>
```

WorkClass will know about interface impl only during runtime and code must look like:

```
String todayWorker = getWorkerNameFromDataBase();
UsefulInterface worker = appCtx.getBean(todayWorker, UsefulInterface.class);
worker.doUseful();
```

Is it possible? And how it must look like?

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend you to use getBean this way. In the Spring documentation, it is written that it could be bad for performance.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.0.2/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean%28java.lang.String%29

> Return an instance (possibly shared or independent) of the given bean
>   name. Provides a measure of type safety by throwing an exception if
>   the bean is not of the required type.
>
> **Note that callers should retain references to returned objects. There
>   is no guarantee that this method will be implemented to be efficient.
>   For example, it may be synchronized, or may need to run an RDBMS
>   query.**
>
> Will ask the parent factory if the bean cannot be found in this
>   factory instance.

It really depends of what do you want to do. Did you tought that you Workclass could be a bean ?

```
public class WorkClass implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private UsefulInterface workerA;
    private UsefulInterface workerB;

    public void setWorkerA(UsefulInterface workerA) {
        this.workerA = workerA;
    }

    public void setWorkerB(UsefulInterface workerB) {
        this.workerB = workerB;
    }

    public void work() {
        UsefulInterface workerToUse;
        if(condition) {
            workerToUse = workerA;
        } else {
            workerToUse = workerB;
        }
        // treatment
    }
}
```

Here the configuration file :

```
<bean id="workerA" interface="UsefulInterface" class="CanDoAlmostEverything"/>
<bean id="workerB" interface="UsefulInterface" class="AnotherUsefulImpl"/>
<bean id="mainWorker" class="package.of.WorkClass">
     <property name="workerA" ref="workerA" />
     <property name="workerB" ref="workerB" />
</bean>
```

Your main class will have to call getBean, but only one time to get the instance of WorkClass.